# Round float to storage it as pixel value of image

Tags: python-3.x

I have a gray input image `Img1` (2D-array, only 1 channel - not RGB), an integer value `bias_value`, and a float value `Step`. I want to create another image `Img2`, where `Img2` has its pixel values with modified values from `Img1`, as follows:

```
for i in range(high):
   for j in range(width):
         Img2[i, j] = round((int(Img1[i, j]) - bias_value) * Step)
```

Note that pixel values from Img1 and Img2 are integers ranging from 0 to 255, but when multiplying by `Step`, each pixel value becomes a float, hence the need to use "round".
Well, the code above works fine, but it longs about 0.4 seconds. I've experimentally checked that my code runtime reduces to about 0.02 seconds only by removing the two loops above, so I'm trying to perform the whole image operation once, without any loop. I've tried:

```
Img2= round((Img1[:, :] - bias_value) * Step)
```

But an error appears: "TypeError: type Array doesn't define **round** method". And, by removing the round part, the code continue, but variable `Img2` does not result in a valid image (you can check it by showing the image with):

```
cv.imshow("Capturing", Img2)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

So the error of imshow: "Unsupported depth of input image".

Any trick to perform the operation above without loop?, but just using 1 line of code?

Comment: I'm using libraries numpy and cv2. I mentioned 4 variables in the problem. `bias_value` is a simple integer (not an array), `Step` is a single float (not an array), and Img1 and Img2 are both image matrix of pixels with 1 channel, i. e. a 2D array of unsigned integer of 8-bit uint8 (ranging from 0 to 255).

Comment: yep, it works by removing round(). That's the issue. I cant remove it because it will be storage as a pixel value (an unsigned integer of 8-bit uint8). Maybe you did not understand the issue but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I wrote the solution in the answer below in order to help other people with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem just replacing the two loops by:

```
Img2= round((Img1[:, :] - bias_value) * Step)
Img2= np.random.randint(0, 255, (high, width)).astype(np.uint8)
```

where np is from

```
import numpy as np
```

Runtime remains less than 0.02 seconds.